# SQL Server 2008: how to design a table with 2 primary keys and ID with autoincrement related to 1 key value

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key, identity, auto-increment

Let me explain this a bit better: I need to design a database that needs to be installed in different locations (which might or not be connected to each other).

My thought was: why don't I use a column in which I put the information about the location (site) as a key and I have another field that contains the ID of the record? For example I need to have a `Customers` table that has a `customer_id` and a `site_id` column.

I know that I cannot create more than one identity columns with autoincrement in a table, though. What I ended up thinking is: is there a way to have only one identity column but related to another column?

For example it would be great if I could have a Customers table like this:

```
site_id cust_id description
1        1       John Doe
1        2       Joseph White
1        3       Carlos Santana
2        1       Mike Jones
2        2       Carl Johnson
```

The `cust_id` must have autoincrement.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You cannot have more than one primary key - but you probably really mean **one** primary key with **two** columns in it - right?

Comment: right Marc. see the sample above...

Answer (score 1):

I have a better suggestion: If you just need the numbers on each side to be unique, why not make them so? In your design you need to repeat the value `1` in every single row in the table. This seems quite wasteful to me. Instead, try giving identity ranges:

On site 1:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Customers
(
  CustomerID BIGINT IDENTITY (1000000000,1)
  , other columns...
```

On site 2:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Customers
(
  CustomerID BIGINT IDENTITY (2000000000,1)
  , other columns...
```

Now not only are you virtually guaranteed to never create a duplicate (unless you create customers at an impressively alarming rate), but you can also immediately tell where a customer was created.

Comment: it's a PITA distributing this solution though... I need to create different DB manually for every site I add...

Comment: @user1648502 no you don't. You make a backup of the first version with no data (you can build such a thing with any decent schema/data compare tool), you restore it on the new server, then you run `DBCC CHECKIDENT` for that server's identity pool. Very easy to automate, too, not a PITA at all. How often will you be doing this? Do you really think it is worse than storing 1, 2, etc. in every single row in the table, and dealing with compound primary keys that have absolutely nothing to do with the data?

Answer (score 1):

You can create PK on two columns

```
create table customers (CustomerRegion int not null,
                       CustomerID int identity(1000,1) not null,
                       primary key (CustomerRegion,CustomerID)
                      )
```

Comment: that is not what I wanted to achieve... the ID autoincrement doesn't depend on the customerRegion. if you do an insert the autoincrement keeps adding no matter what is the region code.
I need the identity to start from 1000 (in your example) if the customerRegion is different or new: see my example.
thanx anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a composite primary key (see the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189039%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) here).

It's not a big deal, but it can be a royal pain in the rear later.  (It's a hassle to join on multiple primary key fields)

Comment: Agreed.  That "extra" column has to come along for the ride on pretty much every query.